# ¿Retorno a los 90s?

Tags: discusión

Como de vez en cuando, he entrado en el sitio sin iniciar sesión. Entro, echo un *vistazo rápido*, y, si no hay *nada interesante*, sigo con otras cosas ...

Hoy me he llevado una pequeña sorpresa ... me he encontrado ... ¡ Esto !

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tardado unos minutillos en recordar que, dentro de pocas horas, será 1 de Abril ... cosas de las franjas horarias.

Supongo que lo del unicornio viene por la página del [*recorrido*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) ¿ verdad ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Personalmente, creo que se han *pasao* ... si la memoria no me falla, en los 90 no había *estelitas de estrellas* siguiendo el ratón ... ;-)

¿ Que os parece a vosotros ?

Comment: Me quedé de piedra cuando lo vi: mi web en 1999 se parecía mucho a esto. Y lo malo del caso es que a mí me parecía preciosa. ¿Qué pensaremos de aquí 20 años de las webs de hoy en día? :P

Answer (score 8):

En mi opinión han cometido una omisión **muy grave** que podría causarles problemas legales. Falta esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y un gif de un sobre dando vueltas tambien XD

Comment: Bueno, seamos condescendientes, al fin y al cabo están UNDER CONSTRUCTION

Comment: http://www.textfiles.com/underconstruction/

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 6):

Lo del unicornio es un tema recurrente en StackExchange, que ya comenzó en el primer [April Fools Day en 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20477/346768), y desde entonces es una especie de meme interno de la comunidad de StackExchange.

En 2011, [los avatares se convirtieron en unicornios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37328/346768).

En [esta pregunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/346768) puedes consultar algunos otros memes de la comunidad, incluyendo a [los unicornios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/346768)